# unable to add json content to an existing json file using Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, fs

I have a json prepared file with key-value pairs as arrays. I am writing a program to add new static json (in the same format) to the existing file using "fs" module. I am aware that we cannot just straight-up append json data to json file. Hence, I converted both file and to-be added data to string using JSON.stringify() first. Post this, I tried to use fs.write / fs.appendFile to get the data inserted using JSON.parse() but I end up getting error! Also, I tried to use .push() mehtod but it throws err - "undefined"

```
let fs = require('fs');
let news = { 
    "person4": [
        {
            "first": "Karan",
            "last": "Mahajan"
        }
    ],
    "person5" : [
        {
            "first": "Sahil",
            "last": "Mahajan"
        }
    ]
};


fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "repository.json" , "utf-8", (err,data) => {
    let x = JSON.stringify(data);
    let y = JSON.stringify(news);
    let z = x+y;
    fs.appendFile(__dirname + "repository.json" , JSON.parse(z) , "utf-8", (err) => {
        console.log("error is " + err);
    });
    
});
```

File: repository.json

```
{   
   "person1": [
    {
      "first": "Nicole",
      "last": "Adelstein"
    }],   
   "person2": [
    {
      "first": "Pleuni",
      "last": "Pennings"
    }],
    "person3": [
    {
      "first": "Rori",
      "last": "Rohlfs"
    }] 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because you're using the JSON.parse/stringify in a wrong way. When you read a file with fs.readFile you receive a string with the whole content. So, what you need to do is to use a JSON.parse on what you received, manipulate the object and then write back to file the result.

You can also change the way you rewrite the file, because when you use appendFile becomes hard to deal with the data and manipulate the json object. To do so, I recommend use writeFile. How could be:

index.js

```
let fs = require("fs");
const i = require("./repository.json");
let news = {
  person4: [
    {
      first: "Karan",
      last: "Mahajan",
    },
  ],
  person5: [
    {
      first: "Sahil",
      last: "Mahajan",
    },
  ],
};

fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "repository.json", "utf-8", (err, data) => {
  let x = JSON.parse(data);
  let y = news;
  fs.writeFile(
    __dirname + "/" + "repository.json",
    JSON.stringify({ ...x, ...y }, 0, 2),
    "utf-8",
    (err) => {
      console.log("error is " + err);
    }
  );
});
```

repository.json

```
{
  "person1": [
    {
      "first": "Nicole",
      "last": "Adelstein"
    }
  ],
  "person2": [
    {
      "first": "Pleuni",
      "last": "Pennings"
    }
  ],
  "person3": [
    {
      "first": "Rori",
      "last": "Rohlfs"
    }
  ]
}
```

Result in repository.json

```
{
  "person1": [
    {
      "first": "Nicole",
      "last": "Adelstein"
    }
  ],
  "person2": [
    {
      "first": "Pleuni",
      "last": "Pennings"
    }
  ],
  "person3": [
    {
      "first": "Rori",
      "last": "Rohlfs"
    }
  ],
  "person4": [
    {
      "first": "Karan",
      "last": "Mahajan"
    }
  ],
  "person5": [
    {
      "first": "Sahil",
      "last": "Mahajan"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Bernardo! I tried running with the above modification but the file still remains unchanged. Moreover, the console prints error is null :(

Comment: @KNIGHTMAHAJAN Could you give more informations? I tried the same code and get the expected result.

Comment: please refer to this sandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-scott-3h68r0?file=/index.js

Comment: @KNIGHTMAHAJAN The codesandbox link you provided is in beta, as they said when editing: _We execute Node sandboxes in a server container. This is still in beta, so we require you to sign in before you can fork a Node sandbox._ ,
therefore, permissions or file manipulation errors are to be expected. If you download the folder from [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-rui-hkhx2i?file=/index.js) and run it on your local machine will work.

Comment: Thanks, @BERNARDO! The code works and new data is getting added.  Could you please illustrate the purpose of JSON.stringify({ ...x, ...y }, 0, 2)  ?

Comment: Sure! The `{ ...x, ...y }` is called [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) basically I am using it to create a new object with the content of the another two and then stringify to become an string and be inserted on the file. The options that I added ( 0, 2 ) only do the outcome prettier and readable, you can see more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter)